# What is Telnet command 255 236 sent by Putty on Ctrl+D?

Tags: telnet, putty

I am connected to a Telnet server with Putty and looking at what is going on on the connection using Wireshark. The Telnet server rejects any Telnet options, so this is a pure NVT.

When I press Ctrl+D in Putty, it sends the following command to the Telnet server:

```
0xff 0xec
```

or, in decimal,

```
255 236
```

This looks a lot like a two-byte Telnet command, with the first byte (255) being IAC. However, while looking at [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), I cannot find any mention of a command number 236 (0xec = 236, not to be confused with the Character Erase (EC) command).

Does anybody knows what this is? Am I missing something in the RFC or is this command defined somewhere else?

Comment: You can see it defined in the putty source in [telnet.c](https://github.com/sourcemirror/putty/blob/master/telnet.c#L38) but I can't find any justification for it in the RFCs (also the nearby SUSP and ABORT commands)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thank you for this info. I went a step further and checked if I could find a helpful log message in the Git history. Unfortunately, this "xEOF" command seems to have been in the Putty source code since the initial commit from 1999, so no help there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://books.google.pl/books?id=t_0HYnWCdUoC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=telnet+0xec&source=bl&ots=xDdOA7VPeT&sig=VlH-3pyqYlmNx3jQHzqsdkkn-wc&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFpP6U1-_RAhXoQJoKHSw9ALYQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%200xec&f=false), it is an End of File command.

The value is defined in [RFC1116](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1116), which was in turn obsoleted by [RFC1184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184), which defines the same EOF value.

Comment: Thank you for this information. This would mean this is a Putty bug then: Putty should not be using this command if it hasn't successfully negotiated option 34 (LINEMODE) first (which my Wireshark trace show it isn't even trying to do). Correct?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but no idea as what should be the correct behaviour in this case.